# Issues when compiling a TCL-DLL wrapper

Tags: c++, dll, tcl, oculus

I am working with a project where I am trying to read data from the Oculus Rift sensors in a TCL-module by using this project found at Github (it is a TCL-DLL wrapper):

> Link: https://github.com/myzb/OculusVr-CmDLL

I have never compiled a dll-file before and I am having some issues when I try to compile their project in Visual Studio 2013. These errors shows up:

```
C2491: 'Tclovr_Init' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
C2491: 'Tclovr_Unload' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
```

Do you have any idea of what I might have missed?

Thanks in advance!

Sincerely, Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two functions need to be *both* exported from the DLL and to have C linkage (so that they have the name in the DLL that the Tcl `load` command implementation expects). Are you defining the `OCULUSVRCMDLL_EXPORTS` preprocessor symbol when building? That changes the declarations for those from being `dllimport` to `dllexport`…

Comment: Defining the preprocessor symbol solved the issue, thanks!
Now I am getting linker tool errors (LNK2001) instead